# Reducing 3SAT to a Set Splitting Problem

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, np, decision-problem

I want to be able to reduce the 3SAT problem to a flavor of set-splitting problem. Basically, given $n$ items and $m$ subsets $S_1, S_2,...,S_m$ of these items I want a yes or no answer based upon the fact if it is possible to color the items red and blue so that each set $S_i$ contains at least one red item and at least one blue item.

I know this this problem is in NP and it is fairly simple to prove (at least that is what I think).

I actually want to prove that the problem is NP hard by reduction from 3SAT. I want to be able to convert an instance of 3SAT into an instance of the aforementioned set-splitting such that a yes instance of 3SAT get mapped to a yes instance of set-splitting and vice versa.

I have a basic intuition about how I can do this: given a 3SAT formula $f$ on $n$ variables I will create $2n+1$ items. One to denote each $x_i$ one for each $\overline{x_i}$ and an extra item. 
I am not quite sure how to proceed beyond this basic intuition. This might be a gap in my understanding of the problem. Is this the right way to approach this? If so, how can I use this intuition to actually prove that this is NP hard by way of reduction from 3SAT?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is a generalization of NAE-SAT, an NP-complete version of SAT (see for example [David Witmer's lecture notes](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15750-s17/ScribeNotes/lecture37.pdf) in which we want each clause to have at least one satisfied literal and at least one falsified literal.

In order to convert NAE-SAT to your problem, identify literals with items, have a set per clause, and also have a set per variable, forcing the two literals to get opposite colors. Details left to you.